# "Unable to read image" error while uploading svg image in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, svg, laravel-4, gd

I have code which working ok for jpg,png images to resize images, here is the code sample.

```
$image = Image::make("{$filePath}/{$fileName[0]}");
// Get the maximum uploaded image width
$maxWidth = Config::get('constants.max_uploaded_image_width');

// Resize the image
$image->resize($maxWidth, null, function($constraint)
{
    // Set an aspect ratio constraint
    $constraint->aspectRatio();

    // Prevent upsizing
    $constraint->upsize();
});

// Save the image
$image->save("{$filePath}/{$fileName[0]}");
```

This one is working great with `jpg` and `png` images, but when i am using `svg` it will return error like `Unable to read image from file`. Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

`SVG` is not supported by `Intervention Image`:

http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/formats

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) to work with `SVG`.

Comment: but i dont want to convert to png, i want svg format. any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You probably wouldn't want to resize the SVG images. So the solution will be to get the MIME-TYPE and skip resizing:

```
if($image->mime() != 'text/svg+xml') {
    // resize
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically SVG is stands for the Scalable Vector Graphics it's type is differ from any other image,It is open in to the web Browser so there is different way to integrate Here is the way how to integrate it.

1) Convert an SVG document into a PHP document.
2) Use the object and embed elements to include an SVG document in an XHTML document.
3) Generate SVG using PHP's echo command. 
4) Generate SVG using the phpHtmlLib library. 
5) Generate SVG documents using the PEAR::XML_SVG package.
6) Generate SVG documents using the PEAR::Image_Canvas package.
7) Integrate PHP , SVG, and AJAX.